# Multiple matching functions error when doing interface.encodeFunctionData

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, bytes, calldata

I have openzeppelin's standard `ERC721` contract.

Below is the helper function that returns `bytes data` that will be used for some purpose.

```
async function getErc721SafeTransferFromTransaction(tokenInstance, args) {
    const txData = tokenInstance.interface.encodeFunctionData("safeTransferFrom",args);
    return txData;
  }
```

When I call that function with deployed `ERC721` instance and `[from,to,tokenId]` as an argument, I get the following error.

```
     Error: multiple matching functions (argument="name", value="safeTransferFrom", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.6.4)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:261:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:273:20)
      at Logger.throwArgumentError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:277:21)
      at Interface.getFunction (node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/interface.ts:210:24)
      at Interface.encodeFunctionData (node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/interface.ts:373:37)
      at getErc721SafeTransferFromTransaction (test/utils/helper.js:30:44)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:533:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
```

Seems like ethers.js is having issue is with `safeTransferFrom` as openzeppelin's standard ERC721 has overloaded `safeTransferFrom` method, one with `data` argument and one without. How can I solve this and get the encoded data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the parameters, as it got 2 function with the same name but with different parameter lengths.

1. in case you want to call without data.

```
const txData = tokenInstance.interface.encodeFunctionData("safeTransferFrom(address, address, uint256)",args);
```

2. in case you want to call with data.

```
const txData = tokenInstance.interface.encodeFunctionData("safeTransferFrom(address, address, uint256, bytes)",args);
```